# What is Slipstream?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, terminology

I know it's a subgenre of scifi and fantasy, but what are the defining characteristics? What makes a story slipstream?

Comment: I thought it was another name for a speculative FTL technology...  now you've peaked my curiosity.

Comment: That "it's a subgenre of scifi and fantasy" is open to debate in a manner similar to [magical realism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_realism) of which there are examples that some would consider Fantasy and/or Science Fictional but the 'Literary Establishment' would absolutely deny.

Comment: Is this slipstream the drive, or the genre?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Slipstream is genre fiction with sci-fi or fantasy elements that aren't crucial to the plot, but provide setting and background.

Comment: So... stuff like Neal Stephenson's *Cryptonomicon* or Kurt Vonnegut's *Slaughterhouse Five*, or am I missing the point?

Comment: @neilfein: Cryptonomicon doesn't count, as everything in that book is science fact, not science fiction. The plot is fiction, the settings were present and past. Slaughterhouse Five is a great example, although I have never before heard it labeled as such.

Comment: I think Christopher Moore is probably another good example, though in the fantasy vein a little more than sci-fi.

Comment: Ah, so that would make most of Jack Vacnes work `SlipStream`, you could re-write 90% of Vances SciFi as fantasy (Spaceships are used for travel only, so chould be sea going vessels etc)

Comment: @DampeS8N - NOT everything in Cryptonomicon is science fact. Enter Exibit A: Enoch Root. Besides, I vaguely recall Stephenson himself explicitly stating that Cryptonomicon is Sci-Fi or SciFi-yish, though I don't have a cite and not 100% certain.

Comment: @DVK: Perhaps I missed something, what about Enoch Root was impossible? If you mean that little event in his life on page 541, I assumed a lying narrator.

Comment: @DampeS8N If you take into consideration The Baroque Cycle then Enoch Root would not fall within the realm of the possible.  Also at the time digitally encrypted currency was still speculative.

Answer (score 1):

Slipstream fiction may or may not have significant fantastical or science fictional elements.  It seems the most critical factor in labelling a tale as slipstream is the sense of cognitive dissonance created by a realistic setting with elements of the sf&f genre introduced to produce a surreal effect.  See [Slipstream(genre)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_%28genre%29) and [this review](http://www.sfsite.com/08b/fv230.htm).